# Why does installing rdnssd remove network-manager?

Tags: networking, apt, 20.04, package-management, software-installation

Why does "sudo apt install rdnssd" remove 7 packages like network-manager etc.?

```
$ sudo apt install rdnssd

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libndp0 libpkcs11-helper1 libteamdctl0 mobile-broadband-provider-info
  openvpn pptp-linux
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  ndisc6
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  network-manager network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rdnssd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 7 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 15,9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10,7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `apt show rdnssd`

Look for the `Conflicts` line:

```
Conflicts: network-manager
```

There's your answer: `rdnssd` and `NetworkManager` cannot exist on the same system simultaneously. They *conflict*.

FYI: Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Core use systemd-networkd instead of NetworkManager. Unless you have bolted NM on, `rdnssd` should work well with those versions of Ubuntu.